# How can I apply logic is the user present in the Frontend Order Model?

Tags: django

I just want If a user Ordered something then the user will be able to rate on the order else can't and will show an error message "You didn't purchase any website". I applied logic 5/6 times in different ways but I couldn't fix the issues.

***Oeder Model:***

```
class Frontend_Order(models.Model):
    USer = models.ForeignKey(User,default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_frontend_order')
    Service_Type = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    Price = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    Number_of_Section = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    Per_section_Price = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    Website_Functionality = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    Email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=True)
    files = models.FileField(upload_to="0_frontend_files/", null=True, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    order_message = models.ForeignKey(Message_Manu,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="message")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)+ str(".") + str(self.USer)
```

***Rating Model:***

```
class Frontend_Rating(models.Model):
    USer = models.OneToOneField(User,default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="frontend_rating")
    Rating = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Feedback = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)+ str(".") + str(self.USer) + str("(") + str(self.Rating) + str("stars") +str(")")
```

***Order View:***

```
def frontend_order_rating(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
 
        if request.method == "POST":
            frontend_rating = int(request.POST.get('frontend_ratting'))
            frontend_feedback = request.POST.get('frontend_feedback')
            
            try:
                Frontend_Rating.objects.create(
                    USer = request.user,
                    Rating = int(frontend_rating),
                    Feedback = frontend_feedback
                    )

                messages.success(request,f"{request.user.first_name}, Thank You for your feedback!")
                
                return redirect("/", userz = request.user)
            except:
                messages.error(request,f"{request.user.first_name}, Sorry! You've already given a feedback!")
                return redirect("/", userz = request.user)

    else:
        messages.error(request,"Please login or create an account.")
   
    return redirect("/")
```

Answer (score 0):

first check if the user ever did an order by

```
if Frontend_Order.objects.filter(USer=request.user.id):
    # your code for thanking for feedback
else:
    # your code for sorry
```

Comment: I tried it before ,not working

Comment: You have `onetoone` relation of user and rating, maybe user has already submitted rating. Did you try another user?